# Will updating from 12.04 to 14.04 break my power pc installation?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, unity, upgrade, powerpc

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity to work on my Powerbook 1.67 GHz G4. I am aware that support will run out next April for 12.04 but it is working really well with my hardware. The updater is now prompting me to upgrade to 14.04 but I know that this hardware is not supported in 14.04 with Unity only Server, Lubuntu or Mate. My question is what would happen if I choose to update? Will it break my installation? If so how? Will I still have CLI so that I can install Gnome or another GUI?

Comment: I would recommend a full image backup, then give the upgrade a try, just go back to your image if it doesn't work.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCKnownIssues

Comment: A great idea and I will do this if I need to. I just hoped someone, somewhere would have done this already and be able to tell me what will happen. 12.04 works so nicely on this machine, I don't want to risk it unless I have to.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that a Lubuntu 14.04 installation on my powerpc G5 worked more or less out of the box, give or take a few things (eg sound). However at first I attempted to install the ubuntu Unity desktop (14.04), and I could not get past the splash screen/login manager. I still had access to a CLI via tty (ctrl-alt-F1 etc) however. In the end as powerpc is not supported for Unity I aborted and went with Lubuntu, and have since successfully upgraded to 16.04.

So my best guess is upgrading to 14.04 may break unity, but not your system. It may also depend on your graphics card; I have an nvidia card and have been struggling with the nouveau driver, and if you have an ATI card you might have better luck. but changing to a lighter Desktop Environment such as LXDE should at least leave you with a usable system, even if graphics are being rendered by your CPU. Then again if Unity was working for you in 12.04, maybe it will work in 14.04.. it might be worth finding out! ;)

Comment: I have twice tried upgrading my G4 Mac Mini from 12.04 to 14.04 .  Each time it failed.  I don't remember exactly what happened, but I do remember that I didn't lose anything.  I just stayed at 12.04 .  Maybe I just need to change my Desktop Environment to LXDE and then try an upgrade.